# A Riley Respite

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix gets the guns.
>   My infix makes things dull.
>   My suffix appears at zero.
>   My whole indicates a lull.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are:

> an **Armistice**

My prefix gets the guns.

> Arm: as in 'to get weapons'

My infix makes things dull.

> Mist:  makes thing dreary and can erode

My suffix appears at zero.

> Ice:  appears at 0 degrees Celsius

My whole indicates a lull.

> Armistice: an agreement in a war to stop fighting for a certain time; ie, a lull